# Use nalgebra with float types from rug

Tags: rust, floating-point, svd, nalgebra

Is it possible to replace the rust `f64` fundamental type with `rug::Float` types?

If so, which traits must be implemented in order to call `svd()` on a nalgebra matrix?

Comment: Have you tried it? What error did you get? It looks like nalgebra relies on num-traits for its genericism, and rug has support for num-traits but you might need to enable [the feature flag for it](https://docs.rs/crate/rug/latest/features#num-traits).

Comment: Yes, I've tried and seems that (at least) the nalgebra::ComplexField trait must be implemented for the rug::Float type...the problem is that nalgebra::ComplexField depends (inherits) on other traits, and before embarking myself to implement all the dependencies , it would be better to know if some (deep) structure of nalgebra rely on rust fundamental types or if someone already have done something similar with arbitrary precision floating point types.

Comment: @MassimilianoMartinelli Did you end up working out a solution to this? I am facing the same problem now.